# An episode from a horror/fantasy type of a show similar to The Twilight Zone but made in the 1980s-1990s

Tags: story-identification, tv

This episode featured a professional sports player, NBA I think, and his demon witch wife. She was pretending to be human but meanwhile was draining his soul or something.

The most memorable part was her bright orange eyes and how she looked at the camera at the end of the episode to reveal how she actually is a demon.

Comment: I've checked. It's not the 1985 Twilight zone remake.

Comment: Feels like Outer Limits but I can't find any matches

Comment: Tales From the Darkside would be another possibility, but also not seeing anything close.